# How to appoint different users to different pages?

Tags: customization

I am having this problem, i need to separate subscribers(all one user type) into two different groups with access to different pages, pages restricted to one group is available to another though they have other pages in common. Can it also be such that when 1 subscribes, depending on weather they are option A or B they are allowed access accordingly.

Comment: Hi Tawanda Joseph, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: @Kraftner i have tried using plugins like restrict content pro and advanced access manager to mention a few. The ones that do get close to what i want will deferentiate between different user groups such as admin, editor or subscriber, i need one that can split one group which is subscribers into two so subscribers have two different access levels. It is a job board site, there are job seekers and job offers but all are subscribers. How do i differentiate them and give them access to different pages